# Java - NullPointerException when referencing an object in a HashMap

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, hashmap

I am currently writing a command line program that is supposed to take in lines from a text file and add data to an array of HashMaps. I currently get a `NullPointerException` when running this method.

```
Public class Vaerdata {
String[] linje;
String line;
String line2;
HashMap<String, Stasjon> stasjonsmap = new HashMap<String, Stasjon>();
HashMap<String, Stasjon>[] regionmap = (HashMap<String, Stasjon>[]) new HashMap<?, ?>[6];


void init() throws IOException{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("stasjoner_norge.txt"));
    BufferedReader brData = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("klimadata2012.txt"));
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        brData.readLine();
    }
    br.readLine();
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        linje = line.split("\\s+");
        stasjonsmap.put(linje[1], new Stasjon(Integer.parseInt(linje[1]), linje[2], Integer.parseInt(linje[3]), linje[4], linje[5], linje[6]));
        }
        if(linje[6].equals("AGDER")){
            System.out.println(stasjonsmap.get(linje[1])); //DEBUG
            regionmap[1].put(stasjonsmap.get(linje[1]).navn, stasjonsmap.get(linje[1]));
            System.out.println(regionmap[1].get(stasjonsmap.get(linje[1]).navn)); //DEBUG
        }
    }  
}
```

My `NullPointerException` happens in this line:

```
regionmap[1].put(stasjonsmap.get(linje[1]).navn, stasjonsmap.get(linje[1]));
```

So my question is: When I have declared the array of `HashMaps` with `<String, Stasjon>` (Stasjon is an object of my Stasjon class, taking info about certain weather stations), why do I get an error in that line? The object in `stasjonsmap.get(linje[1])` has been declared, and I can't understand why it won't allow me to make a reference to this object in my second hashmap.

Every line in the text file, after line one (which I skip in my program) look like this:
 `36200 TORUNGEN_FYR            12 ARENDAL    AUST-AGDER AGDER`

In advance; thanks for your help.

Comment: General advice: Use a debugger to see which reference is `null` or put every method call of the erroneous line on a separate line to see where exactly the exception happens.

Comment: Do you populate `regionmap` somewhere?

Comment: I think, the `if` block should be inside the `while` loop. BTW, what does the `//DEBUG` line prints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you initialize your array of HashMap here

`HashMap<String, Stasjon>[] regionmap = (HashMap<String, Stasjon>[]) new HashMap<?, ?>[6];`

all values in the array are `null`.

You then try to call the `put` method of HashMap on a `null`-reference.

First you have to initialize your HashMaps somehow:

```
for (int i = 0; i < regionmap.length; i++) {
    regionmap[i] = new HashMap<String, Stasjon>();
}
```

Comment: The problem has been resolved, thank you very much. I included a for-loop to initialize all the HashMaps in the regionmap array at the beginning of my init() method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**-** I think you have **not** initialized the `HashMap`, and you called `put()` method.

**-** As `HashMap` is an Object its default value is `null`, so you need to initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

You have created an array of Hashmaps of size 6, but all items in that array are still initialized to null.

You could instead do it like this (which also gets rid of the ugly cast):

```
  private static HashMap<String, Stasjun>[] initRegionMap(HashMap<String, Stasjun>... items) {
    return items;
  }

  HashMap<String, Stasjun>[] regionmap = initRegionMap ( 
      new HashMap<String, Stasjun>(),
      new HashMap<String, Stasjun>(),
      new HashMap<String, Stasjun>(),
      new HashMap<String, Stasjun>(),
      new HashMap<String, Stasjun>(),
      new HashMap<String, Stasjun>()
    );
```

Comment: What if he needs 1000 instead of 6 next time? :D

Comment: Code evolves... He'd have to use a loop. But depending on the actual problem he's trying to solve, perhaps another data structure would fit even better.